# Using the Python debugger with VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pdb

I use the latest VS Code with [miniconda](https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) for Python 3 development and one of the scripts I wrote was gettings stuck when used with the debugger.

This is the command that was executed in the command line by the debugger:

```
cd /Users/*** ; 
"PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}"
"PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" 
/Users/***/miniconda3/envs/ma2/bin/python 
/Users/***/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.1.0/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 63953
/Users/***/power_law_pymc3.py
```

Executing the same exact script directly without the debugger or using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) from the command line works great.

I can see that VS Code runs `ptvsd_launcher.py` for debugging - is there an alternative? Maybe a way to use pdb directly?

Comment: There is only support for ptvsd. How is the "getting stuck"? Feel free to file an issue at github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .